# How to see only videos that are auto uploaded on Google+?

Tags: google-plus, video

How to filter only videos that are auto uploaded on Google+?

Comment: That appears to be a deficit. You can search for `#AutoBackup` or `#Videos`, but not both together. Considering this is Google I'm shocked that there's not a more dynamic search available.